# Create an array of Excel formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I want to create an array/list of formulas in Excel and get as result the array containing the result of each formula.
When I try to create the following array `{1, 2, 3}` it works fine but when I try to create something like that `{sum(1, 2}, sum(3, 4), sum(5, 6)}` I would expect to get the following result `{3, 7, 11}` but instead I get an Excel error.

Do you know if there is any possible way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use `Evaluate("sum(1, 2)")` etc but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically, I have an Excel file where I use the FORECAST.LINEAR formula and I want to use as know_ys/know_xs argument an array/list of values I would implement directly in the formula and not by selecting a range in the file.

For example, I wan to do this kind of thing:
`FORECAST.LINEAR(A, {SUM(b, c), SUM(d, e), SUM(f, g)}, {AVERAGE(h, i), AVERAGE(j, k), AVERAGE(l, m)})`

Here I use SUM and AVERAGE but I would like to do it with any other formula to avoid creating this formulas in a actual cell of the file.

Comment: `array constants` cannot contain formulas.  I suggest either helper columns which implement your desired formulas, or creating the array using VBA